# Simulating Input in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am working on some automated testing in both UE4/UE5 and I was looking for a way to simulate the press of a input from both controller and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You question is tagged C++, but your question does not clearly state what you are looking for.

You could use the [Set Timer By Event](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Time/SetTimerbyEvent/) function to test the behaviour you want. The node can trigger other nodes in an interval that you defined plugging a variable to the `Time` pin input. You might use it to e.g. push a key or set some to (movement) axis to some value. The `Event` pin input could plug into e.g. a keystroke issued by you to start the simulation. If you tick the `Looping` pin input to `True` the node will be executed after `Time` elapsed, which can be used to simulate a series of inputs. Using the `Timer Handle` pin output you can invalidate the timer, that means stopping it.